# Tabulator show progress legend number from different data field

Tags: progress, tabulator

I am trying to build a table with a progress bar column but would like to display a value from another data field.  For example I would like to display a job count from a data field as the legend text and have the progress bar display based on a percentage.  I know I can change the text displayed using the formatterParams in the column definition but how do I show a value from a data field?

I have added an example,  showing where I would like to be able to reference the column field.  For example have the progress bar fill 80% of cell and the legend show a count of jobs, ie: 963.

```
var col_def = [title:"TheJobSource", field:"JobCount", formatter: "progress", formatterParams:{legend: <dataField_string>}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a callback to the `formatterParams` property instead of the object, this would be called when the cell is formatted, you can then use this function to return a custom `formatterParams` object for each cell.

In this example we will assume that you are storing the legend in the `legend` field:

```js
formatterParams:function(cell){
    return {legend: cell.getData().legend}
}
```